# multiple count conditions with single query

Tags: sql

I have a table like below -

```
Student ID | History | Maths | Geography
1               A        B         B     
2               C        C         E
3               D        A         B
4               E        D         A
```

How to find out how many students got A in history, B in maths and E in Geography with a single sql query ?

Comment: @GoatCO its bad test data ;)

Comment: right now I have three select queries .. I want to do this using one query

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get number of students who got A in History in one column, number of students who got B in Maths in second column and number of students who got E in Geography in third then:

```
select
    sum(case when [History] = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as HistoryA,
    sum(case when [Maths] = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as MathsB,
    sum(case when [Geography] = 'E' then 1 else 0 end) as GeographyC
from Table1
```

If you want to count students who got A in history, B in maths and E in Geography:

```
select count(*)
from Table1
where [History] = 'A' and [Maths] = 'B' and [Geography] = 'E'
```

Comment: Thanks :-) I am new to sql and only know basic sql selects. This really helped.

Answer (score 3):

If you want independent counts use:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Condition1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Condition1'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Condition2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Condition2'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Condition3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Condition3'
FROM YourTable
```

If you want multiple conditions for one count use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
WHERE Condition1
  AND Condition2
  AND Condition3
```

It sounds like you want multiple independent counts:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN History = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'History A'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Maths = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Maths B'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Geography = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Geography E'
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to select from multiple select statements

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.* FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS h FROM students WHERE History = 'A') as t1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS m FROM students WHERE Maths = 'B') as t2,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS g FROM students WHERE Geography = 'E') as t3
```